# how can I retrieve Dynamic variables through Post using forloop

Tags: php

I want to retrieve the values using post
Update.php

```
for($o=0;$o<12;$o++)
   {
      $monthname=$months[$o];
      $get=mysql_query("select * from workupdate where Empname='$empname'and 
      Designation='$designation'");
      $i=1;
      echo "<td>";
      echo $monthname;
      echo "</td>";
      while($res=mysql_fetch_array($get)) 
      {
       $getres=array();
       $getres=explode(":", $res[$monthname]) ;
       $t=0;

       foreach($getres as $expres) 
           {
            if(!empty($expres))
             {
               // $sepqua=array();
                //$sepqua=explode("-",$expres);


             echo"<td>";

             ?>
                 <input type="text" name=<?php echo "month$t$o"?> value="<?php echo $expres;?>">    
             <?php
             echo"</td>";
             $t++;
            }
          }

       $i++;}
       ?>
```

retrieve.php

```
  <?php
$mon=array('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
//$month=array();
//$getmonth=array();
for ($i=0;$i<12;$i++) 
{
 echo"<tr>";
  $monthname=$mon[$i];
  echo"<td>";
  echo $monthname;
  echo"</td>";
  echo"</tr>";
 $monappend=""; 
  for($g=0;$g<15;$g++)
   {
  //echo"</tr>";  
  $month="month$g$i";

 if(!empty($_POST[$month])) 
  {
   $getmonth=$_POST[$month];
   echo"<tr>";
   echo"<td>";
   echo    $get=$getmonth;
   echo"<td>";
   echo"</tr>"; 
   $monappend.=$get.":";
  }
  }

  $updatemonth=mysql_query("update  workupdate set ".$monthname."='$monappend' where Empname='$empname' and Designation='$designation'",$conn);
}
```

assume `$_POST[month10]` value is 02 the same value is retrieved for `$_POST[month110]` eventhough  `textbox(month110)` has different value.please help me over this .how can get the value of `$_post[month110]` it  gives the values of `$_post[month10]`

Comment: move your update into the last if-loop.

Comment: Could you var_export($_POST), filter out any data you don't want publicly available and add it to your question via an edit?